# How to create Form Sheet popup for iPad (iOS 8.1)

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, popup

I want to make very basic popup window by using Swift (8.1) with presentation type "Form Sheet", it should be a window that float at the middle of the screen without tales.

[image]

I created two View Controllers, one button and connect the button from one controller to another with parameter "Present As Popover". Second view controller was selected as "Form Sheet", but the result is wrong:

[image]
[image]

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't present it as a Popover.  You want the segue to be Modal and present it as a form sheet.  In the storyboard, click on the segue and change the "Segue" to "Modal"

[image: Storyboard Segue Settings]

### EDIT

In my haste, I used an Objective-C project for setting up an example instead of Swift.  Below is what the Storyboard Segue should be in Swift using the "Present Modally" Adaptive Segue.

[image: Storyboard Segue]

Comment: Indeed… But it's Deprecated Segues, which means Apple can remove it in the future?

Comment: Ah sorry, I took a screenshot out of an objective-c project instead of a Swift project.  Use "Present Modally"