# How to create Form Sheet popup for iPhone (iOS 9.2)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, segue, uistoryboard

I managed to get this working on an iPad view controller exactly like this question:

[How to create Form Sheet popup for iPad (iOS 8.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26701590/how-to-create-form-sheet-popup-for-ipad-ios-8-1)

However when I use the exact same attributes (though I adjusted the size of the view controller course) on an iPhone the view controller covers the whole screen, just like a push segue.

Is it possible to do this on an iPhone? Or is the screen size just too small?

Comment: Q: "Is it possible to do this on an iPhone?"  A: "No" :)

Comment: Modality translates differently to iPhones.  You can duplicate the behavior by creating a custom view and animating it yourself, but the default modal presentation on iPhone is the same as a push.